# Will network interruption trigger monitor_node or link broken in Erlang/Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

In distribution situation, for example 3 nodes running on different machines, they are connected default as clique in Erlang/Elixir. We call them A, B and C (they are connected explicitly by calling network:connect). Suppose network interruption between A and B happens.

1) Will the interruption between A and B trigger the linkage broken (spawn_link) between processes on A and B since we still have C as intermediate connected node. What about monitor_node (will that be triggered on A or B)?

2) Could we still send message from process of A to process of B since C works as intermediate connected node?

3) How does the membership components of Erlang/Elixir solve this situation? Will the connection be recovered and nothing bad really happens after all (no linkage broken, no monitor_node message returned just like everything are recovered immediately)?

Thank you for any consideration on this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Will the interruption between A and B trigger the linkage broken (spawn_link) between processes on A and B since we still have C as intermediate connected node. What about monitor_node (will that be triggered on A or B)?

The default behaviour of Erlang nodes is to connect *transitively*, meaning that when functions like `connect` or `ping` are called from node A to B, if the connection is established A will also try to connect to all nodes known by B i.e. the list obtained when calling `nodes()` at node B.

> 2) Could we still send message from process of A to process of B since
>   C works as intermediate connected node?

It depends, if A is able to connect directly to B with the transitive behaviour that I have mentioned above, then it doesn't make any difference. See below :

`A ----- C ----- B`

This is how you would imagine the links between your nodes if you connect A to C and C to B. But actually it will look like this :

```
A ----- C
\     /
 \   /
   B
```

So even when node C is running, A won't go through it to reach B. But if going through C is the only physical way for A to reach B, then A and B won't be able to communicate anymore.

> 3) How does the membership components of Erlang/Elixir solve this
>   situation? Will the connection be recovered and nothing bad really
>   happens after all (no linkage broken, no monitor_node message returned
>   just like everything are recovered immediately)?

If a monitored node goes down, there will be a message of the form `{nodedown, Node}` sent to the monitoring process so that it can handle the failure. The connection will not be recovered unless the node itself recovers. If the failing node does not hold a critical role in the network for example, and other nodes can still communicate with each other, then you could say that *nothing bad really happens*.

But that would be in my opinion a pretty reckless way to see node failures, and even if Erlang is said to be fault tolerant, it should not be considered *fault acceping* i.e. one should always handle errors.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: So do node in Erlang only have topology knowledge of its directed connected neighbors? Since it is default clique topology, do any node just presume the neighbor is down (no matter if it connected indirectly) if network disruption happens?

Comment: I think that there is no notion of *direction* in the topology. Every connection is bidirectional by default. The `nodes()` function will return the list of nodes that the current node is connected to. If a node becomes unreachable because no more path to it exists, it will no longer appear in the `nodes()` list.

Answer (score 1):

> 1） Will the interruption between A and B trigger the linkage broken
>   (spawn_link) between processes on A and B since we still have C as
>   intermediate connected node. What about monitor_node (will that be triggered on A or B)?
>
> 2) Could we still send message from process of A to process of B
>   since C works as intermediate connected node?

`Erlang` had a service named `epmd(Erlang Port Mapper Daemon)` which will broadcast the nodes' info(ip, name) to other node, and these nodes will save them.
That means, each node has a info map about other nodes.
So if the network interruption can recover and the node are not dead(restart)，nodes can communicate as the same. 
Above's situation can. Now talk about the can not communicate situation, which is `epmd(Erlang Port Mapper Daemon)`  down. At this time, old nodes keep each others information so they can call each other. After restarting `epmd`, the new nodes created now can not call the old ones because old ones do not broad their info.

> 3) How does the membership components of Erlang/Elixir solve this
>   situation? Will the connection be recovered and nothing bad really
>   happens after all (no linkage broken, no monitor_node message returned
>   just like everything are recovered immediately)?

`monitor_node` will receive a message `{nodedown, Node}` if the connection to it is lost.
`spawn_link` just link two process and can only receive [process down msg](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_flag-2).

Comment: What do you mean by "old nodes" vs "new nodes"?

Comment: So, even B is still alive, if A monitor_node B, it will receive {nodedown, B} after connection is lost? (note: we have C still connect to both A and B)

Comment: @chenyuandong  1. A， B create 2. `epmd` down and restart 3. C， D created  : A and B are old nodes, C and D are new nodes.

Comment: @chenyuandong Yes. A will receive `{nodedown, B} `.  > monitor_node will receive a message {nodedown, Node} if the connection to it is lost.  < is from doc.